# Migrated Questions don't show votes in list view

Tags: bug, status-norepro

*Take a look at the vote counter*

### This is the migrated Question in the list view:

[image]

---

### This is the same Question in detail view:

[image]

Comment: This should be migrated to meta

Comment: @Bainternet - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The votes counter is cached, so its possible that you see an older value in the lists, and the actual values only on the individual question pages. [For new questions (less than 10 minutes old) the cache time is 30 seconds, for older questions it's 5 minutes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/views-indicator-inaccurate-shows-one-views-on-question-with-two-close-vote/80857#80857)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. See list view "asked yesterday". And i was def. longer there than 10 mins.

Comment: @kaiser: There is an extra delay, it take 30 views (of the overview page?) before it is recounted. So it is possible you visited this at a time when there were not many other visitors? If you want more attention for this issue you can retag it as `[bug]` and it will show up on the rader of the site owners.

Comment: done.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this.

Looks fine here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite

and here (currently on page 2 at 50 per page)

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest

So, as Jan stated -- probably caching.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Just wanted to mention.